# how to set date and time to dutch

Tags: php, setlocale

I am using this simple script to test on my host which runs on php version 5.6.
The script gives the output "Wednesday" instead off "Woensdag"(dutch)
Why is the day of the week still in English and not in Dutch?
Is this because the server is not correct configured?

```
<?php
/* Set locale to Dutch */
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');

echo date("l"); // output: Wednesday instead off  "Woensdag" (dutch)

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately date is not multilingual. If you want to format a language in another language you need to set locale (as you did in your example) and use [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Formatting options for strftime do result in "Woensdag" (or "mittwoch in German, etc):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_EN');
echo strftime('%A', time()); // for a Wednesday will output: Wednesday
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL');
echo strftime('%A', time()); // for a Wednesday will output: woensdag
```

Unless you want al lot of things to be influenced by `setlocale` you might want to specify that you're doing this for time only (as in the example above). Read on `setlocale` for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Keep in mind you need to have the locales available on your machine for this to work. Check with `locale -a` on linux. `setlocale` has a return value. If it is false something went wrong and you're most likely missing the specified locale.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do echo the strftime but still in English: 'echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y");' gives me Wednesday 14 October 2015

Comment: Do you have the locale nl_NL installed on your machine?

Comment: Well I think I have to contact my host for that. The problem occurred when upgrading from php version 5.3 to 5.6

Comment: if you have console access you can use the tip I provided in the answer: locale -a to see what you have and have not installed.